# Fields not being passed correctly to Props using ReduxForm

Tags: redux-form

I'm using Redux Form in one of my projects (pretty much just copying the dynamic one from Rally Coding), but whenever I access this.props.fields, it simply gives me an array of the names of my fields as opposed to an object.  What's even weirder is that I'm copying and pasting this code into another one of my projects that uses RF and it's giving me what I want from this.props.fields.  Part of me thinks that I set RF up incorrectly, but I did import the formReducer into App.js and combined it with my other reducers.

When I hit the debugger, this.props.fields = ['query', 'numberOfResults'] which is messing everything up.

Here's my code:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

const FIELDS = {
  query: {
    type: 'input',
    label: 'What are you looking for?'
  },
  numberOfResults: {
    type: 'input',
    label: 'Number of Results'
  }
};

class YelpForm extends Component {
  onSubmit(props) {
    console.log('hey cutie')
  }

  renderField(fieldConfig, field) {
    debugger
    const fieldHelper = this.props.fields[field]
    return (
      <div className={`form-group ${fieldHelper.touched && fieldHelper.invalid ? 'has-danger' : '' }`} >
        <label>{fieldConfig.label}</label>
        <fieldConfig.type type="text" className="form-control" {...fieldHelper} />
        <div className="text-help">
          {fieldHelper.touched ? fieldHelper.error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(props => this.onSubmit(props))} >
        {_.map(FIELDS, this.renderField.bind(this))}
        <input type="submit">Submit</input>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};
  _.each(FIELDS, (type, field) => {
    if (!values[field]) {
      errors[field] = `Enter a ${field}`;
    }
  });
  return errors;
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'Yelp Form',
  fields: _.keys(FIELDS),
  validate
})(YelpForm);
```

This is my first question on StackOverflow; thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: For some reason, it started working when I downgraded ReduxForm.  Hopefully this might help someone out!

Comment: I had the same problem. redux-form v6.0.2 passed in an Array of field names to the Component, and v5.2.3 worked (passed in an Object containing the fields).

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading to redux-form version 5.2.3. It seems version 6.0.2 is either buggy, or not documented correctly.